# Spring security 5.2+ SAML2 multiple IDPs logout

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

SAML2 support is the new addition to Spring Security library.

According to this:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/docs/manual/src/docs/asciidoc/_includes/servlet/saml2/saml2-login.adoc

```
Saml 2 Login - Not Yet Supported
    1. Mappings assertion conditions and attributes to session features (timeout, tracking, etc)
    2. Single logout
    3. Dynamic metadata generation
    4. Receiving and validating standalone assertion (not wrapped in a response object)
```

it doesn't support single logout in the current version, which is essential for cases with multiple identity providers.

What would be the right workaround to enable single logout for multiple IDPs?

Answer (score 0):

The single logout feature that Spring Security would provide would be to log out many SPs against one IdP, not multiple.

The typical flow for a user is to log in to some IdP and then be redirected to one or many SPs over the course of their session. When they click logout, it's to end the session they originally established with that IdP.

The way that this would be addressed in Spring Security is via a `LogoutSuccessHandler`. `LogoutSuccessHandler`s are invoked after the SP has successfully terminated their session (clicked the logout button). You can imagine a `LogoutSuccessHandler` that would either redirect to the IDP's SLO endpoint or hit a backend IDP logout endpoint.

It's not very common for an SP to try and merge a session initiated by a user logging into one IdP with one from that same user logging into another IdP, which is the use case I think you are describing. But feel free to add more detail if you feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: In case of a single IDP I would expect single logout to redirect to IDP and log out there, then redirect back to SP to clear cookie. So the next attempt to look at secure content from SP would require a user to enter credentials. As I understand, current implementation only clears cookie/session for SP. The user will not be asked to login for secure content because IDP will redirect immediately back to SP with authentication token, which was never cleared.

Comment: So even for a single IDP I need to work around it by finding IDP URL to log user out. Right? For multiple, I first need to understand which IDP is used and then find its URL. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you'd add a `LogoutSuccessHandler` that would redirect to the IdP. Most IdP's document their logout endpoint.

Comment: As I understand it should be the other way around. I have to hit an IDP URL to logout first and then process redirect back by redirecting it further to the local logout URL.

Comment: Hello Mr @ATrubka, I have found your questions, and I wonder If you  could complete the whole use cases for SAML integration with multiple Idp login and logout?

Comment: Spring Security 5.7 introduced SAML Logout support, which may make this discussion moot. What Spring Security does is logs out the SP and redirects to the IDP with a LogoutRequest. The IDP then redirects back to the SP with a LogoutResponse, which Spring Security processes.